# basic php: why cannot access empty property here?

Tags: php

I am have an instance variable w/ a global scope set in a PHP class. The variable gets set successfully in the constructor. But when I got to access in a getter method I get a PHP fatal error. I'm fairly new to php. Why is `$sid` not getting set?

```
class Wrapper
{
    private $sid = null;

    /**

        public function __construct($data){

        // Retrieve client account automatically
        $sid = (isset($data['client_id'])) ? $data['client_id'] : null;
        echo("set sid to");
        echo($sid);
        $this->client = new Account($sid);  //this is getting set properly
       }
       ...
       public function getSID()
       {
               return $this->$sid;
       }
```

The code that uses the class looks like this (it is a unit test with PHPunit):

```
public function testGetSubsctions(){
    $clientObject = ClientModel::getInstance(7)->read(); 
    $data = array('client_id' => $clientObject->id);
    $this->assertEquals($data['client_id'], 7);
    $hello = new Wrapper($data);
    $this->assertEquals(7, $hello->getSid());
}
```

The code above throws the following error:

```
Cannot access empty property in /path to/wrapper.php  on line 243
```

The code on line 242 is getSid, below

```
public function getSID()
{
    return $this->$sid;
}
```

Comment: and where is the line  243 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first part of the code you show, we can see `return $this->$sid;` but `$sid` is not defined. non-static property has to be called without the `$`

The correct syntax is :

```
public function getSID()
{
  return $this->sid;
}
```

**EDIT:** see the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for more help on the usage of `$this->`, `static` and other things related to OOP in php, and more specifically :

[About properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

[about static keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) (just for your information to see the difference)

Comment: so when you use the -> operator to refer to an instance variable the instance variable does not get the $ is the jist?

Comment: see my edition to the official php documentation. if the property is not static, $this->property_name .

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you set $sid;

```
public function __construct($data){

    // Retrieve client account automatically
    $this->sid = (isset($data['client_id'])) ? $data['client_id'] : null;
    echo("set sid to");
    echo($this->sid);
    $this->client = new Account($this->sid);  //this is getting set properly
}
```

The variable is part of the instance so you have to use the `$this` keyword. Simply using `$sid` refers to a new local variable.

And also there is no `$` sign before sid:

```
public function getSID()
{
    return $this->sid;
}
```